# Group within group in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in following form:

```
ID GROUP DATE
1  A     01-Sep-2017
1  A     02-Sep-2017
1  C     03-Sep-2017
1  C     04-Sep-2017
1  C     05-Sep-2017
1  B     06-Sep-2017
1  B     07-Sep-2017
1  A     08-Sep-2017
1  A     09-Sep-2017
1  C     10-Sep-2017
```

The desired output is as under:

```
ID GROUP START_DATE  END_DATE
1  A     01-Sep-2017 02-Sep-2017
1  C     03-Sep-2017 05-Sep-2017
1  B     06-Sep-2017 07-Sep-2017
1  A     08-Sep-2017 09-Sep-2017
1  C     10-Sep-2017 10-Sep-2017
```

If I try to use simple group by it will club the GROUP field such that A will start from 01-Sep-2017 and end on 09-Sep-2017 whereas it is ending on 02-Sep-2017 and then restarting from 08-Sep-2017. I have tried various analytical functions to first assign a unique number to each of the sub groups to get something like below:

```
ID GROUP DATE        RANK
1  A     01-Sep-2017 1
1  A     02-Sep-2017 1
1  C     03-Sep-2017 2
1  C     04-Sep-2017 2
1  C     05-Sep-2017 2
1  B     06-Sep-2017 3
1  B     07-Sep-2017 3
1  A     08-Sep-2017 4
1  A     09-Sep-2017 4
1  C     10-Sep-2017 5
```

Now it is just a case of simple group by on the new field, but cant get the desired RANK column.

Any help on this or any other approach to achieve the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to solve this is the difference in row numbers method.  It is a bit difficult to explain in pure language, so I invite you to explore the demo below, take it apart, etc., until you can see how it works.  Basically we take the difference between the row number of the entire table, ordered by date, with the row number partitioned by group.  Then, we can aggregate by your group column and this row number difference to get a pseudo group for each block of time you want to target.

```
SELECT
    grp,
    MIN(date) AS START_DATE,
    MAX(date) AS END_DATE
FROM
(
    SELECT
        grp, date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) -
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY date) diff
    FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY
    grp, diff
ORDER BY
    MIN(date);
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

(The demo is in SQL Server, but the query should run on any database which has a normal implementation of `ROW_NUMBER`.)

Comment: Much thanks, it works perfectly. Just a little tweaking needed as per my need.